# Java 8 No trusted certificate found on HTTPS requests

Tags: java, linux, http, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm on linux and I need to use a particular version of java 8 (1.8.0_162) can't use OpenJDK either.

But, I'm getting this error when I try to connect / get / download / whatever from my java program on any **HTTPS url**

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found

I know that the code is right, because its working on production, but I can run the code on my local machine.

I think is something related to certificates, but don't know how to fix.

EDIT: In my lib/security folder I have lots of broken links... Can be that the reason? Where can I get the files?

[image]

There is a pic of my security folder. The ones with an X its a broken link. Which should I replace?

Comment: Well, you could check the root certificates for the urls you're trying to access and check whether they already existed when that version of the JDK was published (seems to be Jan 16 2018) and what key type they're using. I had a similar problem once with the JDK not being able to handle 4096-bit keys. You could also try to add a certificate to `cacerts` directly to check whether it works then. And you might want to check the contents of your `cacerts` and whether it is used at all.

Comment: It isn't on a specific site. Every url which uses https gives me the error. (Like maven central, pe)

Comment: This might be the case but you need to test and check a couple of things if you want to rule them out. You didn't share any code and anyway state the same code works in production so you need to look at your configuration which you didn't share either. Thus all we can do is point you to a couple of things to check, e.g. whether your `cacerts` actually contains a valid root or intermediate certificate for one url that fails (if not that's at least part of the problem).

Comment: "It isn't on a specific site. Every url which uses https gives me the error." - This reminds me of that old joke: "Doctor, when I thouch here it hurts, when I touch here it hurts, ..." - "Well, your finger is broken". ;)

Comment: If `cacerts` or `jssecacerts` is one of the broken links in `JRE/lib/security`, that would definitely cause this problem. For an _Oracle_ JDK (not Open JDK) this is normally an actual file not a link, unless you or someone on your system has changed it. Whatever the cause, fix it. You can get a cacerts file from any JRE anywhere -- it is architecture-independent -- although a relatively recent one (not more than a year or so old) is sometimes better as @Thomas says. Or you _can_ build it from scratch by obtaining and adding all needed certs, but that's a good deal of work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've updated the OP with a pic. Should I replace only cacerts.original ?

Comment: @dragonalvaro `cacerts.original` isn't used by Java, and it's likely a backup file made by something else trying to manage your certificates. For security's sake, you should review the contents of that file, but most likely, renaming it to `cacerts` will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just found the problem and the solution.

The problem was that in my security folder (jre/lib/security) The files inside were broken links to other files that doesn't exists.

I went to the oracle homepage, download a jdk from java 8 linux, and replaced all the files inside the security folder (but no the folder policy).

Comment: Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 for pointing me in the right direction. And thanks everyone who answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file named "cacerts" in the folder %JAVA_JRE_HOME%/lib/security.
This is a truststore for your java runtime environment.
Use "KeyStore Explorer" (or any other keystore program) to open the file (password 'changeit') and add the certificate to trust.

Comment: It isn't on a specific site. Every url which uses https gives me the error. (Like maven central, pe)